# How do I debug why an OSX key binding stopped working?

Tags: macos, keyboard, hotkeys, key-binding

Recently, I've realized that my ^A key binding has stopped working in OSX.

My assumption is that some application has registered ^A as a hotkey, but I don't know that for certain. I don't recall installing anything new lately, but it's certainly possible that I did and just forgot.

Some other pertinent info:

- ^A doesn't work in any application -- this isn't just a Terminal.app issue
- Other control combos (eg: ^E) still work as expected
- Looking through the Keyboard System Preferences pane shows nothing bound to ^A
- A reboot doesn't help

  - However, logging into under a freshly made account *does* cause the issue to go away (i.e.: ^A works for the test account)
- My StandardKeyBinding.dict has the correct value for ^A

  - Note: I don't have a DefaultKeyBinding.dict in /Library/KeyBindings or ~/Library/KeyBindings

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: You can add your own answer below by clicking "Answer your Question". That way you can mark it as accepted in two days and it will be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd still like comments on how to debug this kind of thing in general, but the answer to this point problem is answered here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1172355

> You can fix this problem by deleting
>   the following plist file, which will
>   reset all your keyboard shortcuts:
>   com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist in
>   ~/Library/Preferences, and then
>   logging out and back in again.